# Отправка и чтение данных по COM-порту

Tags: c#, .net, rs232, com-порт

Обращаюсь к вам за помощью, подскажите пожалуйста по следующему вопросу:
К ПК подключено устройство по последовательному **СOM-порту**, используется протокол **RS-232**.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы *отправлять* команды устройству и *получать* ответ.

**Пример кода №1:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace PortDataReceived
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
            string KeyWord = "exit";
            string EnterWord = "";
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler 
            (DataReceivedHandler);

            mySerialPort.Open();

            while(true)
                {

                Console.Write(">>");
                EnterWord = Console.ReadLine();

                if (EnterWord == KeyWord)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Вы вышли из программы");
                    break;

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Отправили комманду на COM-порт");
                    mySerialPort.WriteLine(EnterWord);

                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            mySerialPort.Close();

        }

        private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)                                          
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            //string indata = sp.ReadLine();
            if (indata == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Нет данных");
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine(indata);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**Вывод №1:**
[image: Вывод №1:]
**Комментарий :**

1) Нужно, чтобы выводилась одна строка целиком - **"Service connection opened (COM0)"**
2) Нужно, чтобы выводилась одна строка целиком - **"10 значений в одной строке"**

В цикле программного кода добавлен **ввод** команды (на скрине выглядит как **">>"**. Как сделать так, чтобы ввод команды был доступен только тогда, когда будет полностью получает ответ на запрос?

**Пример кода №2**( отличие - вместо строки string indata = sp.ReadExisting(); используется строка string indata = sp.ReadLine(); ) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

    namespace PortDataReceived
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
            string KeyWord = "exit";
            string EnterWord = "";
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler 
           (DataReceivedHandler);

            mySerialPort.Open();

            while(true)
                {

                Console.Write(">>");
                EnterWord = Console.ReadLine();

                if (EnterWord == KeyWord)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Вы вышли из программы");
                    break;

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Отправили комманду на COM-порт");
                    mySerialPort.WriteLine(EnterWord);

                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            mySerialPort.Close();

        }

        private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)                                          
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            //string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            string indata = sp.ReadLine();
            if (indata == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Нет данных");
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine(indata);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**Вывод №2:**
[image: **Вывод №2:**]
**Комментарий:**

1) После сообщения - **"Data Received"**, выводится пустая строка. 
После ввода команды - **"open"** на скрине из проги("**Advanced Serial Port Monitor**") видно, что на месте пропускa написано - **" [len=1]"**.
Видимо это сообщение не отображается. Как сделать так, чтобы оно отображалось? Либо , чтобы это сообщение вообще не выводилось?
2) Ответ на запрос - **"paramset"** каждый параметр выводится отдельно. Вывод ответа принял такой вид, потому что метод чтения данных изменился с **"ReadExisting"** на **"ReadLine"**.
*Пример №2* мне нравится больше, потому что ответы на запросы - **"open"** и **"rep test"** выводятся должным образом. Только символ ввода запроса - **">>"** портит вид вывода.
Тут нужно сделать также, *чтобы ввод нового запроса был доступен только после конца ответа.* И сделать ответ на запрос - **"paramset"** как в выводе №1(чтобы все поля выводились сразу, а не по очереди отделенными друга от друга сообщением - **"Data Received"**.

**Вывод программы "Advanced Serial Port Monitor":**
[image: **Вывод программы "Advanced Serial Port Monitor":**]
**Комментарий:**

В идеале, в своем коде, я хочу сделать вывод как в этой проге,

только без сообщений типа -**"[len=1]"**. *Только значения параметров.*

*Как быстрее изменить код и не делать его сложным?* Что лучше добавить:

**1)** свой буфер в виде массива и сделать вывод побитово,используя *методы* **"BytesToRead"**,**"ReadByte"** ?

**2)** проверка начала и конца сообщения ?

Постарался описать задачу как можно подробнее, чтобы вы поняли, что мне нужно в точности.

Comment: Вы используете WriteLine для вывода прочитанных данных, но последовательный порт просто шлет байты. Если в какой-то момент ОС вам сообщит, что в буфере есть несколько байт, вы их выведите отдельной строкой, не дожидаясь явного перевода строки от отправителя. А еще ваш монитор пишет не лучшие логи...

Comment: Ну минимум проверять indata на isNullOrEmpty, далее, откуда такие большие задержки? Thread.Sleep(2000). Лучше инициируйте асинхронную операцию чтения данных. Установите протокол - сколько сервер отправляет данных и сколько вы готовы принять.

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы.Задержки использовал для более наглядного вывода. Буду исправлять код, опираясь на предоставленную инфу.